# How to solve a Flex 4.5.1 runtime exception that did not happen in Flex 4.1

Tags: flex4.5

I am trying to upgrade a Flex 4.1 web application to Flex 4.5.1 but am having the following runtime issue:

I have a an mx tree-panel control, with underlying datasource of an xml.
When calling maintree.app_tree.validateNow() (to refresh the UI)
I now get a runtime exception
return types dont match
   virt mx.collections::ISort mx.collections::ICollectionView/get mx.collections:ICollectionView::sort()
   over mx.collections::Sort mx.controls.treeClasses::HierarchicalCollectionView/get sort()

The same code works with Flash Builder 4.0 and FlashDevelop 4.0B that I upgraded to use 4.5.1 SDK.

Having a look at Flex 4.5 and Flex 4.5.1 release notes didn't provide any 'breaking changes'
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+4.5+Backwards+Compatibility

Has anyone else encountered this?
How can I overcome the exception?